# Tool or code for Cache and Memory Bus performances

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiler

I am facing a performance issue on a multi-core (8+) architecture with software written in C++ / VistualStudio / WindowsXP.

Suddenly I realized that I have no idea of the performances of my L1 and L2 cache and CPU->to->Memory bandwidth.

I have tested several tools (including VTune, Glowcode, etc, etc) but all of them fails when tested on load in a multicore architecture (which is the very reason why I need them!).

Can you suggest any other tool which is not so fancy in doing graphs but can give me at least few indications of my cache/memory performances or can suggest snippets of code to manually instrument my application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the EVEREST test suite will check your memory/cpu/cache performance. You may want to look into this site. [Lavalys' Everest Page](http://www.lavalys.com/products/eapm.php?ps=UE&lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

you can use hardware counters to measure the L1 and L2 miss rate; however, I am not too sure which library package to use with a windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [cachegrind](http://wwwcdf.pd.infn.it/valgrind/cg_main.html) ? Its a simulator, of course, but still, it will let you catch most of the real problems.